# Materialize CSS modal getting cropped inside another modal

Tags: css, materialize

I have a modal (datepicker) inside another modal but it is getting cropped because the parent modal is not big enough to display the second modal. Is there a way to make it pop out of the parent modal and be relative to the window and not the parent modal?

By inspecting the datepicker modal I can see that it is bigger than it appears. How is it possible if it's position is set to "fixed"?

```
<div id="first-modal" class="modal">
 <div id="second-modal" class="modal">

 </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:
 [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    container: 'body' //this will append to body
});
```